# Django/Python: Use file uploaded by the user for two different view methods at different times

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

I have a form in my template. The user uploads a file and when this is submitted i call a view method via an Ajax call because i do not want the page to reload, this works fine.

```
$("#formi").submit(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
    var data = new FormData($('form').get(0));

        $.ajax({
             type:"POST",
             url:"{% url 'do_some' %}",
             data: data,
             processData: false,
             contentType: false,
             csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',

             success: function(data){
                 ...},
```

The problem comes when i want to call another view passing the same data (file uploaded) but i do not want the user to upload again the file. I will try to elaborate on this:

Say you have a form, the user uploads a file, submits it and two new buttons appear on the screen. With this two new buttons now you can move around the page (right or left). Press right button and from "Home" page you move to "About" page, but the page do not reload, it is all in the same HTML.

Calling one big function to fill the "About" page, the "Contact" page, etc on the first submit of the form takes a lot of time. I want to use the data to fill the first page quick, then the right button is clicked and fill the next page quick, etc. What i want to do is to "save" that data somewhere and use it when the, for example, "right" button is clicked.

**WARNING**

I DO NOT USE DATABASES FOR THIS WEBPAGE. THE DATA THE USER PROVIDES IS SENSIBLE SO IT CANNOT BE STORED. It will dissapear when the user exits the page

SO, question: Is there a way that i can use the same data i get from the form in another button? Maybe use that button as a second form and pass the file from the first form to this one and "submit it" when is clicked? Save this file in my python code and use it only when that button is clicked? 
Is there a way to delay the ejecution of a view method so the code do not run all together?

Maybe this is an easy question and i am thinking too much

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't want to store it, but you want it to be stored?

Comment: yeah, i missed that one. Do not want to store it. Maybe a global variable where i can save the file and use it all the time?

Answer (score 0):

If you wan't to process that uploaded file later, you must save it somewhere, either in database, on hard drive or in cache. You can't rely on some global django varialbe because there is no guarantee that it will survive between requests (workers, threads on entire WSGI serwer can be reloaded between requests, depending on your WSGI server settings).

If you want to ensure that nobody will retrieve that file from your server, you can encrypt it. On file uploading, encrypt it using some random string and save that encrypted file on your server, send back in response encryption key (you can save it in users cookies for example) so any requests that will use that file again must contain proper key.

Comment: I will try to get more information on how to save it in cache

Comment: What do you think about memcached? could i save the file as a value and use it for every method?

Comment: It depends on your file, but exact place where you will store that file won't matter much.

Comment: Is just a .txt file that i use in every method while the user is in that page, i need a pros opinion that is why i keep asking to you. Thanks